# Why am I receiving empty string PHP curl OpenCart

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to access a function via curl from a different source, that I placed in my OpenCart website which is suppose to get current products stored in the database.

Normally, whenever someone tried to access any page in admin opencart, it will be redirected to login page, which also happens with my curl request. I send the username and password through postfields in order to access the login page as it would manually login, so I can be redirected to my function.

My function would be:

```
public function get_settings(){

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $return = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
        $array = array();
        foreach($return as $ret){
            $array[] = array(
                'product_id' => $ret['product_id'],
                'product_image' => ($ret['image']) ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($ret['image'], 40, 40) : $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 40, 40),
                'product_name' => $ret['name'],
                'product_model' => $ret['model'],
                'product_quantity' => $ret['quantity'],
                'product_price' => $this->currency->format(number_format($ret['price'], 2, '.', ''), $this->config->get('config_currency')),
                'product_status' => ($ret['status'] == 1) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

While my curl request would be:

```
$params = array(
            'username' => $this->session->userdata('admin_user'),
            'password' => $this->session->userdata('admin_pass'),
            'redirect' => $this->session->userdata('domain').'admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/get_settings'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->session->userdata('domain').'admin/index.php?route=common/login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($return);
```

I do not receive any error messages. I checked in log files. I only get an empty string.
OpenCart verifies on login if any redirect post value exists, which I do send, in order to send me forward to that particular page, which is the function that returns my JSON

Comment: When you curl with credentials to OC admin after that you should receive this session `token`, or `user_token` if you use OC 3. And add it to you redirect link. `'redirect' => $this->session->userdata('domain').'admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/get_settings&user_token=$user_token'`

Comment: I initially did that, and received the same result